# How to tokenise all strings in a numpy array of strings

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nltk

I'm trying to find the word position of specific list of strings within a list of sentences. I'm using numpy, sklean and nltk to achieve this. In my actual code I have 10000's of sentences and the word lists are equally as long, and so I'm trying to avoud regular for loops and lists/sets as they are not fast enough.

So far I have written the code below

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
import nltk
import numpy as np
from sklearn import feature_extraction

sentences = ["Great place and so amazing", "I like doughnuts", "Mary had a little lamb"]

posWords = ["great","like","amazing","little lamb"]

# Here we see which words from the wordlist appear in the sentences.
cv = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(vocabulary=posWords)
taggedSentences = cv.fit_transform(sentences).toarray() # This vector is of size (noOfSentences x noOfWordsInPoswords)

taggedSentencesCutDown = taggedSentences > 0
taggedSentencesCutDown = np.column_stack(np.where(taggedSentencesCutDown)) # This is a list of tuples (sentence, wordIndex)


sentencesIdentified = np.unique(taggedSentencesCutDown[:,0])


for sentenceIdx in sentencesIdentified:

    tokenisedSent = np.array(tknzr.tokenize(sentences[sentenceIdx]))
    wordsFoundSent = np.where(taggedSentencesCutDown[:,0] == sentenceIdx)
    wordsFoundSent = taggedSentencesCutDown[wordsFoundSent]

    matches = np.where(posWords[wordsFoundSent[:,1]] in tokenisedSent)
    sent = tokenisedSent[matches]
```

Ideally what I want is the following array

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 4], [1, 1, 1], [2, 3, 3]]

# where each triplet represents [sentenceNumber, wordNo, Position in sentence]
```

I have two things that I need here:

1. To use NLTK tokenise to tokenise all sentences in the taggedSentencesCutDown array (preferably without using a for loop, as I'm currently doing, as my real array has 10,000s of sentences and words)
2. Can CountVectorizer handle strings like "little lamb"? At the moment this is not being caught. Is there some way to do this as efficiently and elegantly as countvectorizer would?

Thanks

Comment: Tried `gensim`?

Comment: Hi alvas. I have had a look, and this seems great for topic modelling, but in my case I already have a pre-loaded list of words. Not sure how it would help. Thanks

Comment: For 1. you can take a look at [joblib](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) to parallelize loops

Comment: It's just because `gensim` has some tokenization and phrasal functions that outputs vocabulary vectors. . Maybe that'll help.